# IBM MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN recommended practices

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

Okay, we saw another one of these during testing, and I'm trying to figure out the recommended practice to deal with these. We are using JMS to connect, and I've set this on our `MQConnectionFactory`:

```java
cf.setClientReconnectOptions(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT)
```

and this:

```java
cf.setClientReconnectTimeout(86400)
```

...which seems like it should recover from network interruptions, IBM MQ server being restarted and/or down for quite some time and so on (for a day). And yet...I had to restart our client application because when trying to place a message on a queue, we received a `MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN` error.

Comment: See if this link helps => https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/203577/mq-client-application-encounters-mqrc-connection-b/

Comment: How was the queue manager restarted?  If the admin did a endmqm with out the `-r` flag it will not reconnect.

Comment: I have to check with someone else when they get back, but I don't think the queue manager was restarted in the time between the application coming up and when the error was seen. Although that is good information in general.